# State from Context returning in Screen Component but not App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to pass two forms of state (user + signedIn) to my app.js for my React Native app, so I can access those values and determine if a user is signed in.

If I try to import my context into a given component screen (in this case, using SignInScreen) then the context returns perfectly and I can console log my state. See example below.

```
const SignInScreen = () => {
  const {signIn, user, signedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const signInFunction = async () => {
    await signIn(email, password, navigation);
    console.log(user); // Returns []
    console.log(signedIn) // Returns true
  };

  return (
    // Component code
  );
};
```

However, in my app.js, when I try to access my context, it returns undefined - indicating it hasn't got access to it.

```
import {AuthContext, AuthProvider} from './src/context/AuthContext';

function App({navigation}) {

  const {user, signedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user); // errors out, stating 'undefined is not an object'
    console.log(signedIn); // same as user
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <AuthProvider>
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
          <AuthStackScreen />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

For reference, here's part of my Context code:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(true);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, signedIn }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? How can I access my two forms of state from my context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access your `AuthContext` outside the `AuthProvider`

To deal with auth and navigation you should do something like this:

```
function RootNavigator({ }) {
  const {user, signedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user); // errors out, stating 'undefined is not an object'
    console.log(signedIn); // same as user
  }, [])
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <AuthStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And :

```
function App({navigation}) {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthProvider>
        <RootNavigator />
      </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a very smooth solution - disappointed I didn't think of it myself! Thanks a lot, works pretty well.